# How to add data to the child node of a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to add data `{"address" : "http://ebay.com"}` to the second child of this json data i.e in the bracket with the data `"api" : "Ebay"`.

How can I do that with jQuery?

```
{"Amazon":[
    {"price":"19,799.00","delivery":"FREE","api":"Amazon"},
    {"price":"29,999","delivery":"FREE","api":"Ebay"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Where did it fail? You are only showing half your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
var obj = {"Amazon":[ {"price":"19,799.00","delivery":"FREE","api":"Amazon"},{"price":"29,999","delivery":"FREE","api":"Ebay"} ] };
obj.Amazon[1].address = "http://ebay.com";
```

or use `$.merge(obj1,obj2)` function

```
var obj = {"Amazon":[ {"price":"19,799.00","delivery":"FREE","api":"Amazon"},{"price":"29,999","delivery":"FREE","api":"Ebay"} ] };

$.merge(obj.Amazon[1], {
    address: "http://ebay.com"
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxhm80d/)